# How to start the camera activity by shaking the phone

Tags: android, android-service, accelerometer, android-sensors, android-camera-intent

**I have building an app, my objective is to start the camera activity from service by shaking the phone.
I can launch the toast but not an activity.
Instead of displaying a toast i want to launch the camera activity. Here is my code, how to launch an camera activity by shaking.**

Background_service.java

```
public class Background_service extends Service implements SensorEventListener
{
    boolean flag=false;
    private long lastUpdate;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    int count=0;
    final static int cameraData = 0;
    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private Uri fileUri;
    ImageView iv;
    Intent I;
    Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {

        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {
        flag=true;
        Log.d(MainShake.TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        flag=false;
        Log.d(MainShake.TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
    {
    }

    private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) 
        {
            float[] values = event.values;
            // Movement
            float x = values[0];
            float y = values[1];
            float z = values[2];

            float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z) / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
            long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2)
            {
                if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 2000) 
                {
                    count++;
                    return;
                }
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Please fill all the field...!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

            }
        }
    }


    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {

        getAccelerometer(event);

    }
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        // register this class as a listener for the orientation and
        // accelerometer sensors
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),             SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause()
    {
        // unregister listener
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    }

}
```

ShakeEventListner.java

```
public class ShakeEventListener implements SensorEventListener {


      /** Minimum movement force to consider. */
      private static final int MIN_FORCE = 10;

      /**
       * Minimum times in a shake gesture that the direction of movement needs to
       * change.
       */
      private static final int MIN_DIRECTION_CHANGE = 3;

      /** Maximum pause between movements. */
      private static final int MAX_PAUSE_BETHWEEN_DIRECTION_CHANGE = 200;

      /** Maximum allowed time for shake gesture. */
      private static final int MAX_TOTAL_DURATION_OF_SHAKE = 400;

      /** Time when the gesture started. */
      private long mFirstDirectionChangeTime = 0;

      /** Time when the last movement started. */
      private long mLastDirectionChangeTime;

      /** How many movements are considered so far. */
      private int mDirectionChangeCount = 0;

      /** The last x position. */
      private float lastX = 0;

      /** The last y position. */
      private float lastY = 0;

      /** The last z position. */
      private float lastZ = 0;

      /** OnShakeListener that is called when shake is detected. */
      private OnShakeListener mShakeListener;

      /**
       * Interface for shake gesture.
       */
      public interface OnShakeListener {

        /**
         * Called when shake gesture is detected.
         */
        void onShake();
      }

      public void setOnShakeListener(OnShakeListener listener) {
        mShakeListener = listener;
      }

      @Override
      public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
        // get sensor data
        float x = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
        float y = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
        float z = se.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

        // calculate movement
        float totalMovement = Math.abs(x + y + z - lastX - lastY - lastZ);

        if (totalMovement > MIN_FORCE) {

          // get time
          long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

          // store first movement time
          if (mFirstDirectionChangeTime == 0) {
            mFirstDirectionChangeTime = now;
            mLastDirectionChangeTime = now;
          }

          // check if the last movement was not long ago
          long lastChangeWasAgo = now - mLastDirectionChangeTime;
          if (lastChangeWasAgo < MAX_PAUSE_BETHWEEN_DIRECTION_CHANGE) {

            // store movement data
            mLastDirectionChangeTime = now;
            mDirectionChangeCount++;

            // store last sensor data 
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            lastZ = z;

            // check how many movements are so far
            if (mDirectionChangeCount >= MIN_DIRECTION_CHANGE) {

              // check total duration
              long totalDuration = now - mFirstDirectionChangeTime;
              if (totalDuration < MAX_TOTAL_DURATION_OF_SHAKE) {
                mShakeListener.onShake();
                resetShakeParameters();
              }
            }

          } else {
            resetShakeParameters();
          }
        }
      }

      /**
       * Resets the shake parameters to their default values.
       */
      private void resetShakeParameters() {
        mFirstDirectionChangeTime = 0;
        mDirectionChangeCount = 0;
        mLastDirectionChangeTime = 0;
        lastX = 0;
        lastY = 0;
        lastZ = 0;
      }

      @Override
      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

with

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Background_service.this, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);    
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Background_service.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is needed when you are starting Activity from a Service

Comment: Its not working, I want to launch the camera activity.

Comment: Please check my comment about the FLAG.